# Extract subject and body text from Gmail messages and export to CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, gmail

My current project is to take a set of emails from my gmail account and create a book from them, where each letter is a chapter.
I wrote up a Google Script snippet that successfully extracts the subject, date, and body text from all emails under a certain
label and writes them to a Google Document. This is not quite ideal, as I would prefer to ultimately have all this text in 
markdown or LaTeX for formatting more carefully, but I was only familiar with how to to write to a Google Doc, based on the 
Gmail API.

The fastest way for A to B for me would be to figure out how to alter this code so that it writes the text to a CSV file, containing
`subject`, `date`, and `body` columns. From there, I can process and parse it out into LaTeX and assign the necessary header styles and
formats there instead; however, I don't see much guidance on that file format in the API. Any guidance on how to adapt this script for 
that purpose would be very welcome. Thanks.

```
function collectLetters() {

  var fileName = 'OUTPUT_GOOGLE_DOC_FILENAME';
  var labelName = 'MY_LABEL';
  var timeZoneName = 'GMT'
  var dateFormat = "dd | MM | yyyy"

  var docBody;
  var subject;
  var date;
  var body;
  var message;
  var num;
  var datePar;
  var bodyPar;
  var subjectPar;
  var numPar;

  // get the handle for label
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  // Create a new Google Doc
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(fileName);

  // get all the threads from label
  for (var i = threads.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

    // EXTRACT FROM EMAIL: date, subject and body
    message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    subject = message.getSubject();
    date = Utilities.formatDate(message.getDate(), timeZoneName, dateFormat)
    body =  message.getPlainBody().replace(/\r\n\r\n/gm,'aaaLINEBREAKERaaa').replace(/\r\n/gm,' ').replace(/  /gm,' ')
    var splitBody = body.split('aaaLINEBREAKERaaa');

    // APPEND TO GOOGLE DOC: Date (as Header)
    datePar = doc.getBody().appendParagraph(date);
    datePar.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);

    // APPEND TO GOOGLE DOC: Subject (as Subtitle)
    if (subject.length > 0) {
      subjectPar = doc.getBody().appendParagraph(subject);
    }
    else{
      subjectPar = doc.getBody().appendParagraph("no subject");
    }
    subjectPar.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.SUBTITLE);

    // APPEND TO GOOGLE DOC: Body (as Normal)
    docBody = doc.getBody()
    splitBody.forEach(function (paragraphText) {
      this.appendParagraph(paragraphText).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL);
    }, docBody);

    // Start a new page
    doc.getBody().appendPageBreak();
    //Logger.log(subject);

  }

}
```

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts regarding how to write a CSV file by using Google Apps Script. I suggest to checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script  and to search for [tag:google-apps-script] and [tag:google-drive-sdk]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7142008/1595451

Comment: Hi, thanks for the direction. I did look through Google's API and like I say wasn't able to see a way to work with non-native Google Drive documents. The stackoverflow solution there appears to make use of the DocList which was deprecated a number of years ago.

Comment: See the other answer

Comment: Thank you for that help; I seem to have found the solution (or thought I had) by using `DriveApp.createFile('filename.txt', content_string)`. where content_string is the entire content of the file, separated with commas and line breaks. I am getting a strange error at this line though, that says "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." Even if I put a line in my code that just does DriveApp.createFile('a.txt', 'hello'), it will also fail on that line with the same error. Running that command in a different script works, though. So I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Hi, have you tried it with another project, or created a new project? Do you have the solution? If not please edit the question with more detail on how are you doing it.

Comment: @Kessy very strange: I just created a new project, copied in the functions, ran it: no problems. If I do it in the other project I keep getting the "server error". How can this be?

Comment: It can happen, you can file a bug if you want on Google Public Issue Tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/) so they can see if there is anything wrong. For this case, since the problem is solved, can you post your solution and mark the question as fixed, so more people can benefit from it?